# Oncomplete its not working in my transition

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I have this transition. I want to make a image that is in the block in position "desplazar" dissapear and then delete it.

```
transition.to(block[desplazar], {time=14000, alpha=0, onComplete=timer.performWithDelay(12000, borrado(desplazar),1) })

local function borrado(desplazar)
    block[desplazar]:removeSelf()
end
```

But i'ts not working, the image is dissapearing inmediatly and i think the image is going to to dissapear when the transition is complete, also i have put a delay in the function but it`s not working.

Hope you can help me

Thanks

I made it this way also

```
transition.to(block[desplazar], {time=14000, alpha=0, onComplete=timer.performWithDelay(12000, intime(),1) })

local function intime()
    print ("intime")
    borrado(desplazar)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code will work

```
    local function borrado(desplazar)
        block[desplazar]:removeSelf()
    end 


transition.to(block[desplazar], {time=14000, alpha=0, onComplete = timer.performWithDelay(12000, function() borrado(desplazar) end),1})
```

just remember when using transition and timer do not just call the function with an argument because you will not achieve the time you want it to trigger just like this

```
 timer.performWithDelay(12000, borrado(desplazar))
```

it will just trigger the function without the time you assign.
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK onComplete parameters expect a function as the parameter, not the results of a function call.  You cannot call another function directly as in the:

```
 onComplete = timer.performWithDelay(12000....)
```

example.

The best way is to create a function that does the work you want to do when complete:

```
 local function handleOnComplete(target)
     target:removeSelf()
     target = nil
 end
 transition.to(block[desplazar], {time=14000, alpha=0, onComplete=handleOnComplete } )
```

The handleOnComplete gets a parameter passed to it which is the object that was transitioning.  I don't understand why you want to wait another 12 seconds after the transition is complete to actually remove it.  If that's important, you can put a timer in handleOnComplete() to delay the removal a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the result of calling `borrado(desplazar)` to timer.performWithDelay. You need to pass a function to performWithDelay which will call `borrado(desplazar)` when the timer calls the passed function.

Comment: It isn't working. I made the change(i write it down in the question), but it's executing the removeself inmediatly. I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Your amended code still calls the function immediately instead of letting the timer call the function. But I see you've been given a snippet of code that does what you want. I hope you see the difference I was trying to point out now.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
transition.to(block[desplazar], {time=14000, alpha=0, onComplete=function()
    timer.performWithDelay(12000, borrado(desplazar),1)
end })

local function borrado(desplazar)
    block[desplazar]:removeSelf()
end
```